# LC50 calculation from bootstrap GLM List

Tags: r, list, glm, statistics-bootstrap

I am trying to calculate LC50 from a list of bootstrapped GLM output

I have the output of bootstrapped GLM in a list (named results) as such:
(I have just put in the last result for ease rather than the whole list)

```
$thetastar[[100]]    
Call:  glm(formula = dead[x] ~ concentration[x] + factor(female.no[x]), 
family = binomial, data = subset.data.48hr)

Coefficients:
      (Intercept)       concentration[x]  factor(female.no[x])3  factor(female.no[x])4             factor(female.no[x])7  
           0.7386                 0.1869                -0.8394                -5.6613                   -2.9576  
factor(female.no[x])8  factor(female.no[x])9  
          -1.5329                -2.7826  

Degrees of Freedom: 354 Total (i.e. Null);  348 Residual
(1265 observations deleted due to missingness)
Null Deviance:      484.2 
Residual Deviance: 257  AIC: 271
```

using `dose.p` from the `MASS` package I am trying to calculate the LC50 for each individual within the model which has run

```
dose.p(results$thetastar[[100]], cf = c(2,3), p = 0.5)
```

which returns

```
              Dose       SE
p = 0.5: 0.2227249 0.161769
```

From what I understand this is the LC50 for `factor(female.no[x])3.` i.e. into `dose.p` I have put `cf = c(2,3)` which i take to be column 2 and column 3, the `concentration` and the `factor(female.no[x])3.`

Is this correct?

secondly:

Is there a way I can get LC50 for each of the females, i.e. `factor(female.no[x])3`,  `factor(female.no[x])4`,  `factor(female.no[x])7` and so on, I don't see how i can get `dose.p` work work along the differing variables without manually changing the code `cf=`:

```
dose.p(results$thetastar[[100]], cf = c(2,3), p = 0.5)
dose.p(results$thetastar[[100]], cf = c(2,4), p = 0.5)
dose.p(results$thetastar[[100]], cf = c(2,4), p = 0.5)
```

finally:
My results are stored in a list, How do i get `dose.p` to work along the list, would it be something like:

```
test=matrix
for(i in 1:results){
test[i,]= dose.p(results$thetastar[[i]], cf = c(2,3), p = 0.5)
```

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `cf` argument to `dose.p` takes the columns of the intercept and the log-dose.  (If you are using concentration, isn't it an LC50?)

For the default animal (that isn't 3, 4, 8 or 9), you can use the `(Intercept)` and `concentration[x]` columns, `cf = 1:2`.

For the other animals, you want the intercept plus a factor.  For example, for animal 3, you'd want column 1 plus column 3 (as well as column 2 for the concentration).  Unfortunately, `dose.p` won't accept a specification like that, so you'll have to rerun your model without an intercept.

Add a `0` to the formula to achieve this:

```
glm(
  dead[x] ~ 0 + concentration[x] + factor(female.no[x]), 
  family = binomial, 
  data = subset.data.48hr
)
```

Now each `factor(female.no[x])` will contain the "intercept" for that animal.

Comment: Ok, so the output would then give me each of the intercepts for each individual, would I then need to get the LC50 for each combination. i.e dose.p(results$thetastar[[100]], cf = c(2,3), p = 0.5)
dose.p(results$thetastar[[100]], cf = c(2,4), p = 0.5)